# How to get values from different table using association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've two tables in my Postgres database structures given below:

```
CREATE TABLE tables(
 id serial NOT NULL,
 name character varying(255),
 table_state_id integer,
 table_type integer,
 CONSTRAINT tables_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE table_states
(
 id serial NOT NULL,
 name character varying(255),
 CONSTRAINT table_states_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Table Model :

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :table_type, :table_state_id, 
 belongs_to :table_state
end
```

TableState Model:

```
class TableState < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :color_code
 has_many :tables
end
```

In View I'm accessing like that:

```
= debug @table_data.table_state.name      # Where `@table_data` is a variable from `tables` table
```

Through association I want to access `name` column of `table_states` table whose ID is present in `table_state_id` column of `tables` table. How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at the official guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I used associations but when I'm accessing the `name` field of `table_states` table then getting this error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @jcm Check the code.

Comment: @Avishek so what is the problem with `@table_data.table_state.name` expression? do you get an error?

Comment: yes "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Maybe `table_state` really is `nil` for `@table_data`.  Have you checked?

Comment: Assuming you have ` has_many :tables` in your table_state model. You are having everything right in your code. `@table_data` is object of model Table. There must be nil saved in your `table_state_id`.

Comment: Try run `select table_state_id from table_states` on your db console you will surely get nil rows.

Comment: `table_states` don't have `table_state_id` column.

Comment: I have miss typed it `select table_state_id from tables`

Comment: table_state_id is present in my table with values, that's not a problem

Comment: Error indicates that your table_state associated object is nil. this `@table_data.table_state` will return `table_state` object and error referring this to nil.

Answer (score 0):

You are having everything right in your code. There must be nil saved in your `table_state_id` in your `tables` table.

Error indicates that your `table_state` associated object is nil. this `@table_data.table_state` will return table_state object and error referring this to nil.

Try run `select table_state_id from tables` on your `db console` and see results. And make necessary changes in record through `db console`.

For future you can also use `try` to rescue such problem (specially production mode)

```
= debug @table_data.table_state.try(:name)
```